# Microsoft flexgrid Control : Run-time error '438' Object doesnt support this property or method

Tags: ms-access, vb6, msflexgrid

I am maintaining a legacy Microsoft Access application that is using the [Microsoft Flexgrid 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228849(v=VS.60).aspx). It recently started causing the following error:

> Run-time error '438' Object doesn't
>   support this property or method

People say that this error can be caused by the [KB960715](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/advisory/960715.mspx) security update being applied, which sets killbits on various ActiveX control methods which were deemed a security risk. But this or no other security update has been applied recently.

Others say that installing [Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Service Pack 6 Cumulative Update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=cb824e35-0403-45c4-9e41-459f0eb89e36&displaylang=en)  will update the flex grid. This requires VB6 to be installed as a prerequisite so I installed that on my PC and then the update, and retrieved the updated MsFlxGrd.ocx file(Version: 6.1.98.12) and copied to the application machine, but the error still prevails.

Someone [here](http://www.developersdex.com/vb/message.asp?p=640&r=6570804) says you can disable the killbit in the registry. But there are afew hundred nodes in the location they suggest, none of which has the same guid as the one they point out.

Any ideas?

Comment: I know you didn't do it, but using an outside data grid control in an Access app indicates that the orginal developer was basically not really competent as an Access developer. Access doesn't need a non-native data grid because it's own datasheets and continuous forms provide all the flexibility you need, and are fully bound.

Comment: @David That is interesting to know. I'm not an Access Developer myself, so was hoping I could just apply a band-aid  solution. But I guess if all else fails I can look into removing the flex grid.

Comment: My guess is that the original developer was a refugee from a development environment (such as VB) where unbound grids are the norm and was annoyed by the way Access's bound "grid" behaves (e.g., continuous forms). You might be opening a boatload of problems by trying to replace the grid control with a continuous forms. On the other hand, if you can't get the thing working...